# One point compactification, Hausdorff space in which every point has a compact neighborhood. Show $X'=X\cup\{\infty\}$ is compact and connected

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a non-compact connected Hausdorff space in which every point has a compact neighborhood. Show $X'=X\cup\{\infty\}$ is compact and connected, $X'$ takes on the one point compactification, where $X'$ denotes the [Alexandroff one-point compactification of $X$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-point_compactification).

Another question I'm solving to prepare for an exam. To show $X'$ is compact, what do I take as the open cover of $X'$? And I am looking for an outline of why $X'$ is connected

Comment: You have to consider *all* open covers of $X'$, to check compactness. And $X$ is dense in $X'$. The closure of a connected set is connected.

Comment: The way you phrased your question it seems incomplete - you did not say what topology you take on $X'$. Although you probably mean [one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-point_compactification). Another thing is that you do not mention $X$ in the body of your question at all. (Only in the title.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak yes I did mean that. Changed to reflect such.

Answer (score 1):

How do you topologize $X'=X\cup\{\infty\}$?

If you take the topology given by defining a set to be open if, and only if it is either an open subset of $X$ or if it contains $\infty$ and its complement is compact, then $X'$ is called the [Alexandroff compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension), and under the conditions you impose it is compact.

For connectedness, take $A,B\subseteq X'$ an open partition. Then notice that $A\cap X,B\cap X$ form an open partition of $X$, so one of them (wlog $A\cap X$) must be empty. This implies $A=\{\infty\}$. But this singleton cannot be open (as this would happen if, and only if $X$ were compact to start with).